# Amazon Ubuntu Postgres - Won't Connect to Localhost

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to postgres using the following engine string:
`sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql://username:password@localhost:5439/dbname`

And I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.31.43.180" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

I know the service is running:

`sudo service postgresql status`

returns:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-08-27 19:21:06 UTC; 4min 21s ago
Process: 1310 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1310 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 0
Memory: 0B
CPU: 0
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Aug 27 19:21:06 ip-loc-al-ip-add systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Aug 27 19:21:06 ip-loc-al-ip-add systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Also, it does appear that it's listening on localhost ('I've also tried feeding it the ip and not just the dns), at minimum:

`netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Also, the following in config files:

`postgresql.conf`:
    # - Connection Settings -

```
listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                     # (change requires restart)
```

`pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/24            md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Lastly, I have no need or desire to have this accessible from outside connections; this is merely a locally accessed db.

Comment: The server is listening on port 5432 and you're trying to connect to 5439.

Comment: Over and above @PauloAlmeida's excellent spotting you may want to consider using Unix domain sockets; less security implications (seeing as you listen on localhost, v4 and v6) and you get roughly double the performance w/o the IP overhead.  http://www.cybertec.at/postgresql-performance-advise-unix-sockets-vs-localhost/

Comment: Of course it was something that stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have an mistake on port number
you should connect on postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname instead of postgresql://username:password@localhost:5439/dbname
54